Latex Beamer - Add left padding to table of contents
I have changed the style of my table of contents in a beamer template, but now I want to add an horizontal padding to the left of this frame. How can I do it while keeping my custom configuration?
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage[spanish, provide=*]{babel}
\uselanguage{Spanish}
\languagepath{Spanish}

\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[circle]
\setbeamercolor{section number projected}{fg=white,bg=red!80!black}
\setbeamerfont{section number projected}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{size=\large}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contenido}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{Introducción}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{Investigación y Diseño}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{Referencias}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



You could redefine the section in toc template and change the left skip how you want:
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage[spanish, provide=*]{babel}
\uselanguage{Spanish}
\languagepath{Spanish}

\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[circle]
\setbeamercolor{section number projected}{fg=white,bg=red!80!black}
\setbeamerfont{section number projected}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{size=\large}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=6ex% <- change value here
  \llap{%
    \usebeamerfont*{section number projected}%
    \usebeamercolor{section number projected}%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{0ex}{1ex}{2ex}
      \color{bg}
      \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{.75ex}}{1.2ex}
      \pgfusepath{fill}
      \pgftext[base]{\color{fg}\inserttocsectionnumber}
    \end{pgfpicture}\kern1.25ex%
  }%
  \inserttocsection\par}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contenido}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{Introducción}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{Investigación y Diseño}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{Referencias}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



This seems to do the tricky, thank you so much!

@mupfelix You're welcome!
